# Split Database Security

Tags: sql, security, privacy

I'm working on an .NET MVC SQL application that will contain sensitive data, for example- HIV test results or income. I want to error-proof this privacy as much as possible so no one except the user can access it (think Joe the Plumber having his information hacked by a state employee).

I read hear that splitting the database in two doesn't seem reasonable:
[Is splitting databases a legitimate security measure?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7158857/is-splitting-databases-a-legitimate-security-measure)
although I've heard of this being done. If we could just use two tables... better.

But when I say error-proofing, I mean impossible for ANYONE in our company to access both databases/tables. I'm thinking about putting access to the application code (which would access both databases) and to both databases in the hands of a deep-pockets third party (like PWC or EY) for when the government came calling or some other real need to see both data sources came along.

Anyone have any thoughts on the cleanest way to do this? We'd want to design the tables such that most queries would not require access to both data sources so the relative cost in throughput wouldn't be that much.

Comment: There is database software out there that lets you assign permissions at the table level.  However, you seem to want to assign permissions at the record level.  I'm not sure if that's possible.

Comment: @DanBracuk I believe DB2 gives that level of control. Of course, even DB2 still has privileged users who can grant themselves permissions.

Comment: Define "impossible". Because making things that an application can do strictly impossible for a person to do is... impossible.

Comment: Think of the Academy Awards. It's impossible for someone outside Price-Waterhouse to find out who the winners are ahead of time (in theory, anyway). So if no one person in our company has access to both databases (or tables if it can be done that way) and if access to the part of the application software that pulls data from these sources is locked down, we can eliminate the opportunity for anyone to access both name and results. A trusted third party will have the key, not anyone in our company. Kind of like a chastity belt for critical data. Hopefully nuke codes are this secure...

Comment: For the Oscars, PWC don't have to allow outsiders direct access to the store of actual votes, certainly not read access, and probably rely on some combination of technology, restricted physical access, trust, money, and contract and tort law for their internal security. My guess would be that of those internal factors, the first is the least important. If you need query access in software, you're just not going to be able to protect against a colleague with source-code and physical access from getting at the data. If you knew the history of nuke codes, you'd probably be _terrified_.

Comment: The big questions really are: under what circumstances, by whom, and by what method, does the sensitive data need to be accessible?

Answer (score 0):

You can encrypt a column of data in SQL. So the columns which has the sensitive data e.g. HIV test results/income, you can encrypt the data while storing it in the DB.

Check the details here:
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms179331.aspx
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb964742.aspx

Let me know if it helps.